# Counter to count from 0 to 100 on Button Click

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have an asp.net page with a script manager and update panel to avoid the postback event for the page (trying to run client side on this). I want to add to the button click event a counter to count from 0 to 100 and when complete set the txt property of a text box? How to do this??

Comment: 1 to 100.. seconds ? minutes ? if just "count", a simple for 0 to 100 doing nothing will work. Of course, it's not the most elegant answer

Comment: just a simple number count 1 to 100, never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: `for(int index = 0;index < 100;index++);` This will auto-increment index from 0 to 100, and then, after that, you can put the code you want.. A simple counter. But, if you need count in seconds, minutes, or some kind of unit of time, you will need something better. That's why I said that is not the most elegant answer. But, if this work for you, tell me and I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: it will work thank you!!

Comment: @ElVieejo: since it is asp.net, the bare loop is probably not enough. I suspect the intention of the task was to display the counter, not only loop it.

Comment: do you want it to count on a timer or increment when you click?

Comment: tell us, since is homework, if it's not enough, I won't post it.